# REST update not working

Tags: rest, angularjs, merge

I am having problems updating list items using REST calls within an angularjs SPA. I've tried HTTP and ajax methods but both do not work and give different errors. (I am only trying to update Description with some static text to prove it works.)

Both ways are contained in a factory service:

```
testLabApp.factory('service', ['$http', function ($http) {

  var updateBooking = function (booking, callback) {
  ....HTTP/AJAX REST code here...
  }

return {
  updateBooking: updateBooking
}
}]);
```

**HTTP**

```
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Bookings')/items(" + booking.Id + ")",
        body: { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.BookingsListItem' }, 'Description': 'Description Updated' },
        headers: {
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "IF-MATCH": "*",
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            accept: "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        }
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log("[updateBooking] POST worked");
        console.log('[updateBooking] Id = ' + data.Id);

        callback(data);

    }).error(function (er) {
        console.log('[updateBooking] Error = ' + er);
    });
};
```

I get an error 415 Media Type wrong but answers online say add 'Content-Type' header which I have done. Unless it is wrong ?!

---

**AJAX**

ajax seems to be a common way to make REST calls and I borrowed this from another POST on SharePoint StackExchange which had similar problem.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/teams/technology-cell-79-new-stores-retail-implementations/testing/testlab/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Bookings')/items(" + booking.Id + ")",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            '__metadata': {
                'type': 'SP.Data.BookingsListItem'
            },
            'Description': 'Description Updated'
        }),
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('[ajax update success] ' + JSON.stringify(data.d));
            alert("Update successful.");
            callback(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
            alert("Update failed")
        }
    });
```

The app returns an error:

> ```
> {
>     "readyState": 4,
>     "responseText": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"The parameter __metadata does not exist in method GetById.\"}}}",
>     "responseJSON": {
>         "error": {
>             "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
>             "message": {
>                 "lang": "en-US",
>                 "value": "The parameter __metadata does not exist in method GetById."
>             }
>         }
>     },
>     "status": 400,
>     "statusText": "Bad Request" 
> }
> ```

Which I do not understand as there is no `getById` call in the request.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: try specifying the full url instead of the relative url.

Comment: That url...  Are you on prem or online?  If on prem, are you SP1?

Comment: I entered the full path including the http:// so company.sharepoint.com/teams/...' and it said 'Access is denied'

Comment: @wjervis It is SP2013 Hosted online.

Comment: O365? If so, try using `{"Description" : "Description updated."}` as your body, and set `Content-Type` to `application/json; odata=nometadata`.  This isn't a solution, I'm just curious of JSON light works.  If it doesn't, you need to double check your url's.  Also, you don't mention apps anywhere, so I'm assuming that this is not an app.

Comment: @wjervis - will try as you suggest - but to answer app question - this is an angularjs app launched from a CEWP on a .aspx page. It works, but is messy (a bit slow) but I don't have permissions to add a SP Application.

Comment: @wjervis - I made the change and get the same error. Checked the URL and fiddler shows as POST /teams/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Bookings')/items(253) HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found to work was to use following as URL:

```
url: "/teams/technology-cell-79-new-stores-retail-implementations/testing/testlab/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Bookings')/getItemByStringId('" + booking.Id + "')",
```

and the following headers:

```
headers: {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    "IF-MATCH": "*",
    "X-Http-Method": "PATCH"
```

and it works.

Comment: Nice One thank you, have tried about 40 different ways and wasted a at least a day on this!